# Including description texts in QlikView Reports

Tags: qlikview

How to include large text description in QlikView Dashboard Reports to ease the visualizations of the users?
Can anybody suggest an example on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find demonstrations of QlikView Dashboards at http://demo.qlik.com, some of these have similar features to what you are looking for and may be downloaded for free. You can then inspect them to discover how certain features are implemented.